# Should I be closing HKEY?

Tags: registry

If I do:

```
HKEY lKey = NULL;

if(AssocQueryKey(..., &lKey) == S_OK)
{
    :
    if(RegCloseKey(lKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //success
        int a = 0;//<- goes through here
    }
    else
    {
        //failure
        int a = 0;
    }
    if(RegCloseKey(lKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //success
        int a = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //failure
        int a = 0;//<- goes through here
    }
}
```

It would appear that lKey needs to be closed, but the documentation for [AssocQueryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says nothing about it, and the help for [RegCloseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%20RegCloseKey) specifically says "the handle must have been opened by the RegCreateKeyEx, RegCreateKeyTransacted, RegOpenKeyEx, RegOpenKeyTransacted, or RegConnectRegistry function".

Should I be closing lKey? If so, how?

Comment: Try it. If RegCloseKey(lKey) returns ERROR_SUCCESS on a successful call to AssocQueryKey then you know you did the right thing

Comment: You're closing it twice?

Comment: @sean I'm closing it twice, yes. First time to see if it closes without error. Second time to see if it closes with an error. (Because I'm trying to figure out if I *need* to close it.

Comment: ERROR_SUCCESS is no proof that the user should close it. What if the underlying system is handle's owner?

Comment: @Dialecticus: That's a good point. What if AssocQueryKey isn't doing an increment on the handle, then my RegCloseKey does a decrement, causing it to hit zero and be closed, but the system still has a handle to it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to be at fault. Consider this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the code in which the key is closed after obtained with AssocQueryKey.

Comment: I'm not convinced one way or another by that code: it seems to be a 3rd party user that's provided it (not Microsoft).

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure about how handles are managed over time in your process using the [Handle utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655).  Run your program in a debugger, and look at its handle usage (esp. Registry category) before and after the call to `AssocQueryKey`.

If there's a new Registry handle after the call, my guess is you have to close it, because afai can see nobody else is going to.

Comment: I already did this using ProcessExplorer and what you describe happens.

Comment: That new handle will stick around until you close it, is my guess. The docs appear to be incomplete. Note that this API is a helper around a COM interface, which is also poorly documented in this area.

Answer (score 0):

An `HKEY` needs to be closed. Nobody else is going to close this one for you, so you need to do so.

Comment: What if AssocQueryKey isn't doing an increment on the handle, then my RegCloseKey does a decrement, causing it to hit zero and be closed, but the system still has a handle to it somewhere?

Comment: It's a new key. The documentation will just be lagging.